# send post request using node-trello module

Tags: api, node.js, trello

I am new to trello api and i am using node.js with it. GET request is working fine with node.js but when i am sending POST request to store list in the particular board then it gives me a unauthorize error. my code is :

```
t.post('/1/boards/board_id/lists?scope=read,write',{text:'test'}, function(err,data){
       if(err){       
           console.log("err "+err); 
           return res.send(err);
       }
       else{
        console.log(data);
        return res.send(data);
       }
   });
```

please anyone tell me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of things that could be going wrong.

First, did you request an api token with scope=read,write? If you're following the instructions at https://github.com/lmatteis/node-trello, you need to do

https://trello.com/1/connect?key=YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY&name=MyApp&response_type=token&scope=read,write

to get a token capable of read and write (replacing YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY with your actual public key).

Second, just to make sure, you are substituting the board id in question for board_id in the post URL, right?

Finally, 'text' should probably be 'name'.

So to put it all together, here is something that should work:

```
var Trello = require("node-trello");

var t = new Trello("[YOUR API KEY]", "[YOUR TOKEN THAT YOU GOT BY HITTING trello.com?connect URL ABOVE]");

t.get("/1/boards/[THE ID OF THE BOARD]/lists", function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
console.log(data);
});

t.post('/1/boards/[THE ID OF THE BOARD]/lists', {name:'test'}, function(err,data){
    if (err) {
      console.log("err " + err);
    } else {
     console.log(data);
    }
  }
);
```

If you would like to check the attributes of a token you have issued, you can do that via the API, too (see https://trello.com/docs/api/token/index.html).